# Reschedule broadcastreceiver android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have an `AlarmManager` which sets a `repeating alarm.`  (Not actually an alarm, but send mail). So in the BroadcastReceiver I do the actual sending of the mail. But to send mail one needs Internet. So when the phone doesn't have an Internet connection the email doesn't get sent. How do I  `"snooze"` the action which is inside onReceive() in my BroadcastReceiver? Do I make a new Receiver which fires with this (when phon haz internietz) or???

```
    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {

        ConnectivityManager cm
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ai= cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return ai!= null;
    }
```

EDIT:
Got it to work. Used a IntentService which checks every 10 minutes if internet is avaliable, and if: send mail. The IntentService is started from my BroadcastReceiver, where the email initially is to be sent, if there's no internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Use Background Service Which Checks The Internet Connection.

if Internet available it just send the Email unless start your service which checks the internet connection in every minute until the email send and after that close your service.

Comment: Thanks. Got it working. I've edited my post with the solution